# How to put a specific .csv file information in a specific matrix location?

Tags: matlab, file, pixel, text-processing

I have many files (e.g. 100) that contains the intensity of the 512x512 pixels of a CCD camera, each files being at a different light frequency.
Those files are formatted like this :

```
1, 1, 602
1, 2, 598
1, 3, 546
```

The first number is the Row of the pixel, the second one is the Column of the pixel, and the last one is the Intensity on the pixel.

I'd like to have an array for each of these pixels. Here's my code so far :

```
%the user selects the "many files"%
filenames = uigetfile('*.csv','','','Multiselect','on');  

%here to know the number of different frequency for each pixel
NumFiles = numel(filenames);  

%There are 512x512 pixels, each with NumFiles different intensities
Pixel = cell(512,512,NumFiles);
```

After this part, I'm not quite sure how to proceed. I want the Pixel(1,1,:) to be all the Intensities of my first pixel, these informations being taken from each files.

Marc-Olivier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
%the user selects the "many files"%
filenames = uigetfile('*.csv','','','Multiselect','on');

%here to know the number of different frequency for each pixel
NumFiles = numel(filenames);

%There are 512x512 pixels, each with NumFiles different intensities
Pixel = cell(512,512,NumFiles)
count = 0
num_pixels = size(Pixel,1)*size(Pixel,2)

for k = 1:NumFiles
    fid = fopen(char(filenames(k)));
    C = textscan(fid, '%d, %d, %d')
    Pixel(count + sub2ind(size(Pixel),C{1},C{2})) = num2cell(C{3});
    count = count + num_pixels;
    fclose(fid);
end
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the "count" part.

Why "count = count + num_pixels;"?

Comment: @Marc-olivierLessard This is all about the [`linear indexing`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.htm) used for `Pixel`. The first file will be used to index into the first `num_pixels` elements of `Pixel`, second file for `num_pixels+1` to `2*num_pixels`, third file for `2*num_pixels+1` to `3*num_pixels` and so on, which is taken care by `count` that goes from `0` to `num_pixels` to `2*num_pixels` and so on respectively. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: I realised I had an error, and I did not specify the filepath. I added     [filenames,filepath] = uigetfile  How can I correctly use the fopen now? I tried "fid = fopen(char(filepath, filenames(k)));" but it won't work. Any idea?

Comment: Just do this - `[filenames,filepath] = uigetfile('*.csv','','','Multiselect','on');
filenames = fullfile(filepath,filenames)`. Rest of the code stays the same.